# NextJs app using JavaScript toISOString() in SWR causing infinite API calls

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I setup the following example Next.js app to test a problem I am seeing when using the `toISOString()` JavaScript function on a variable being included in a `useSWR` call to an API end-point:

Below is the code for `pages/user/[id].tsx` where `toISOString()` is called:

```
import NextLink from "next/link";
import {
  Link,
  Flex,
  Box,
  Text,
  SimpleGrid,
  Heading,
  Alert
} from "@chakra-ui/core";
import useSWR from "swr";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
type Data = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
};

const fetcher = async (url: string) => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw Error("Yo that's NOT OK!!!");
  }
  const data: Data = await res.json();
  return data;
};

const UserData = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;
  const today = new Date();
  const yesterday = new Date(today);
  yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
  const ssd = yesterday.toISOString(); // TROUBLE
  // const ssd = "2021-08-16T19:27:51.630Z"; //fine

  const result = useSWR(`/api/user/${id}/${ssd}`, fetcher, {
    revalidateOnFocus: false
  });
  const data: Data = result.data;
  const error: Error = result.error;

  if (error) {
    return <Alert status="error">Loading failed: {error.message}</Alert>;
  }

  if (!data) {
    return <Alert status="info">Loading...</Alert>;
  }

  return (
    <SimpleGrid columns={2} width="2xs" spacingY={4}>
      <Text fontWeight="bold" marginRight={4}>
        UserID
      </Text>
      <Text>{data.id}</Text>

      <Text fontWeight="bold" marginRight={4}>
        Name
      </Text>
      <Text>{data.name}</Text>

      <Text fontWeight="bold" marginRight={4}>
        Email
      </Text>
      <Text>{data.email}</Text>
    </SimpleGrid>
  );
};

const UserPage = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <Flex flexDirection="column" alignItems="center">
        <Heading marginY="2rem">User</Heading>
        <UserData />
        <NextLink href="/">
          <Link marginY="2rem">
            <Text fontStyle="italic">Go back home</Text>
          </Link>
        </NextLink>
      </Flex>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default UserPage;
```

Line 34 of `pages/user/[id].tsx` is where `toISOString()` is called and triggers multiple API calls as shown in the browser console (console statement added to `/pages/api/user/[...params].ts` line 7 - see full example code below). The `toISOString()` function seems to act as if it were a `useState` function in Next.js, and thus triggering API calls that do not seem to stop.

Any ideas on how to use `toISOString()` and not have it trigger multiple API calls with `useSWR()`?

Below is a copy of the full example app:

https://codesandbox.io/s/consume-next-js-api-routes-with-the-swr-library-on-the-client-side-forked-mzgwz?file=/pages/user/%5Bid%5D.tsx

Comment: Please include a [mre] of the code involved, rather than making people go back and forth to your codesandbox, if they even have access to it. See [ask].

Comment: @w-patrick-gale, kindly review the answer and let us know if it solved your issue

Comment: Thank you @AppCity for the answer. HM, I embedded example code within the question (thank you, let me know if I should include more). I still do not understand why the ISOString function needs to be outside of the function running the SWR. In my production code I had the ISOString function and the SWR code within the main export function. When I moved the SWR code out of the main export function and into a separate function (eg. the UserData in the answer), and passed in the ISOString value, that resolved the infinite API calls. But why infinite API calls in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your updated code which solves your trouble of infinite API calls, just move the ISOString to parent.

```
import NextLink from "next/link";
import {
  Link,
  Flex,
  Box,
  Text,
  SimpleGrid,
  Heading,
  Alert
} from "@chakra-ui/core";
import useSWR from "swr";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
type Data = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
};

const fetcher = async (url: string) => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw Error("Yo that's NOT OK!!!");
  }
  const data: Data = await res.json();
  return data;
};

const UserData = ({ ssd }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;

  // const ssd = "2021-08-16T19:27:51.630Z"; //fine

  const result = useSWR(`/api/user/${id}/${ssd}`, fetcher, {
    revalidateOnFocus: false
  });
  const data: Data = result.data;
  const error: Error = result.error;

  if (error) {
    return <Alert status="error">Loading failed: {error.message}</Alert>;
  }

  if (!data) {
    return <Alert status="info">Loading...</Alert>;
  }

  return (
    <SimpleGrid columns={2} width="2xs" spacingY={4}>
      <Text fontWeight="bold" marginRight={4}>
        UserID
      </Text>
      <Text>{data.id}</Text>

      <Text fontWeight="bold" marginRight={4}>
        Name
      </Text>
      <Text>{data.name}</Text>

      <Text fontWeight="bold" marginRight={4}>
        Email
      </Text>
      <Text>{data.email}</Text>
    </SimpleGrid>
  );
};

const UserPage = () => {
  const today = new Date();
  const yesterday = new Date(today);
  yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
  const ssd = yesterday.toISOString(); // No More TROUBLE

  return (
    <Box>
      <Flex flexDirection="column" alignItems="center">
        <Heading marginY="2rem">User</Heading>
        <UserData ssd={ssd} />
        <NextLink href="/">
          <Link marginY="2rem">
            <Text fontStyle="italic">Go back home</Text>
          </Link>
        </NextLink>
      </Flex>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default UserPage;
```